# How to add [Member] email address in a custom subscription?

Tags: azure-devops

We added a new custom field to set a 'reviewer' for a Test Case work item.

I want to add a new subscription that will send an email to the [Member] assigned to in the new custom field as such:
[image: Screenshot of Notification Popup]

Is there any way to use the [Member]'s email address in the DELIVER TO field? Or is this approach just not possible in DevOps?